# gpgee command line equivalent - gpg arguments

Tags: windows, gnupg

I want to using gpg in windows batch scripts and i've got little problem. Now I'm using gpgee with nice GUI. I want to use  gpg with command line interface.

Gpg script should sign and encyrpt text files, so i try this

gpg -u login -ser key_owner datafile

but, when i try to compare file from this command and gpgee, there are difference, the gpgee file has  size is two times larger.

Does anyone know the equivalent gpg options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. The GPGee has option "--encrypt_to_self" and it is enabled by default. So if someone would like to do this from command line should write something like this

```
gpg -e user_to_encrypt --encrypt-to your_user filename
```

Answer (score 0):

gpg always encrypts and also compresses the files. So, any file encrypted with gpg will have a smaller size than the original file. Is GPGee doing any post encryption processing on the file?

Comment: No it doesnt make any post encryption processing.